# Aptana Studio Rails Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I am trying to get Aptana Studio setup with RadRails in Ubuntu for Rails development, but have run into some snags.

I have the RadRails plugin installed and I have both ruby and rails installed.  However, when I try to create a new Rails Project, I get the error "Rails not found:  It appears that you do not have the rails gems installed for your current Ruby interpreter."

It looks like the path to both ruby and rails are linked correctly in Preferences.  The quote above makes it seems like they should be related somehow, but I don't understand that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install rails through the IDE, which I still do not understand, but it is now working.